# Базы данных C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, sqlite, sql-server

Хочу сделать програму на С#. Суть программы в том чтоб загрузить из интернета список товаров и потом с ним работать локально. (Уже поключения к интернету не будет) + потом (через день, неделю) пользователь подключается к интернету и сохраняет свои изменения.

Порядо действий мне понятен:

- Получить дамп базы с сервера (На сервере база MySql)
- Сохранить данные на компе пользователя
- Работать с товарами локально.

Потом

- Создать дамп базы
- Отправить на сервер
- Сохранить в серверную БД

Теперь к вопросам:

1. Я только начал изучать C# и открыл видео уроки. И там используют MS SQL. С ним все ясно, проблем нет, НО (как я понял) для работы етой базы нужно было установить MS SQL Server. Для разработки установить его проблем нет но пользователь который получит екзешник не будет и у себя сервак базы поднимать... Как тут быть? Использовать SqlLite? Или пользователю не нужно будет ничего делать.
2. Как передать данные с одной базы на другую? Делать прямое подключение безопасно? Или принять просто текстовый дамп базы с сервака?
3. Свои данные пользователь будет получать по логину и паролю. Логин и пароль я могу проверить первый раз (есть подключение к интренету). А как потом проверить вход пользователя (При запуске програмы нужно проверять, даже если нету подключения)? Сохранить локально и сравнивать? Как сохранить пару(логин, пароль) локально и безопасно? Думаю в простой txt в корне програмы не очень правильно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня была похожая задача. Есть одна удаленная база, основная, с которой нужно было брать данные, изменять локально и отправлять обратно в основную базу.
Я сделал так.

Создал локальную базу на sqlite - не требует каких-то там настроек серверов.
Создал в ней аналогичную структуру таблиц. Вытягивал данные из основной базы в свою.
Изменял, потом отправлял обратно.

> Логин и пароль я могу проверить первый
> раз (есть подключение к интренету). А
> как потом проверить вход пользователя
> (При запуске програмы нужно проверять,
> даже если нету подключения)? Сохранить
> локально и сравнивать?

В sqlite создаешь пользователей и для них настраиваешь авторизацию. Без подключения интернета.